# Reading memory from another process on Mac

Tags: c#, macos, readprocessmemory

I'm building a library for reading memory that I'd like to expand to Mac OS.

Among many other functions, the one main function used by many of the methods is [`ReadProcessMemory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-readprocessmemory);

```cs
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(
    [In] IntPtr hProcess,
    [In] IntPtr lpBaseAddress,
    [Out] byte[] lpBuffer,
    [In] SIZE_T nSize,
    [Out] out SIZE_T lpNumberOfBytesRead
);
```

I'm now wondering what the equivalent for this is on Mac. Looking around online (of course it's hardly documented at all), I think the method signature should look something like this;

```cs
[DllImport("...")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
static extern int vm_read_overwrite(
    [In] IntPtr target_task,
    [In] IntPtr address,
    [In] SIZE_T size,
    [Out] byte[] data,
    [Out] out SIZE_T outsize
);
```

[`vm_read_overwrite`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/kernel/1585371-vm_read_overwrite) is also what's used by [several Rust libraries](https://github.com/rbspy/read-process-memory/blob/master/src/lib.rs#L155-L161).

---

What library/package is `vm_read_overwrite` part of? Is the signature correct? Perhaps additionally, can I use conditional compilation to use the different functions, or do I have to use `RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
    [DllImport("libc")]
    static extern int vm_read_overwrite(
        [In] IntPtr target_task,
        [In] IntPtr address,
        [In] uint size,
        [Out] byte[] data,
        [Out] out uint outsize
    );
```

This works on my machine. Hope it helps.

Comment: Perhaps a little noob question, but how did you test this? I'm having trouble getting a simple console app to work. The generated `.app` folder won't run on a Mac device.

Comment: just call the function in `Main` with defaults of parameters, it returns successfully on my box.

Comment: btw can you accept my answer? I need some reputation points to comment posts